# fstream and sstream processing: An input repeats

Tags: c++

I have a text file as follows:

```
1 A Rocket-1 1.2
2 B Rocket-2 2.3
3 C Rocket-3 3.4
Invalid Format Line 
4 D Rocket-4 4.5
5 E Rocket-5 5.6
```

As you can see, the format followed is: `<int> <char> <string literal> <float>`

I want to extract the individual data types from each line and print them. I did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in;
    in.open("input.txt");
    if (in) {
        while (getline(in, x)) {
            istringstream iss(x);
            iss >> i >> c >> s >> f;
            cout << "\n\nInteger:" << i << ", Character: " << c << ", String: "
                << s << ", Float: " << f << endl << endl;
        }       
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nError reading input file\n";
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Integer:1, Character: A, String: Rocket-1, Float: 1.2

Integer:2, Character: B, String: Rocket-2, Float: 2.3

Integer:3, Character: C, String: Rocket-3, Float: 3.4

Integer:3, Character: C, String: Rocket-3, Float: 3.4

Integer:4, Character: D, String: Rocket-4, Float: 4.5

Integer:5, Character: E, String: Rocket-5, Float: 5.6
```

As you can see, one of the lines (3rd) is repeating. **Whenever I have a line in invalid format, I just want to ignore it, and smoothly (without crashing) transition to the next valid format line.** Please suggest changes in my code to handle this.

Comment: @nhgrif - mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the result of the stream insertion. If it's not the right format, it will be in an invalid state:

```
if(!(iss >> i >> c >> s >> f)) // skip the loop if not correct format
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that the invalid string was placed inside your istringstream, from which you then tried to extract according to a valid format. This of course fails, so variables i, c, s and f retain their original values. If you would like to ignore the invalid lines, you should query the fail bit of istringstream. Something along the lines of

```
if ( iss.fail() ) {
    continue;
}
```

should do the trick.
From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
>   expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set

Answer (score 0):

You can check ios_base::iostate for eofbit, failbit or badbit after extraction. see http://www.dcs.uni-pannon.hu/smidla/web/cplusplus/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/index.html